# Creating measure in PowerBI programatically while embedding report in the browser

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am looking for a way to programatically create a measure while embedding powerBI report in the browser.
I need this in order to enhance the reports with dynamic properties based on the data I own.

I have checked all the [Documentation for the powerbi-client](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/javascript/api/powerbi/powerbi-client/) as well as the code available in the code for the [powerbi-report-authoring](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-report-authoring/tree/master/src/extensions) library and could not find any way of doing it.

I am starting to think, that this might not be possible, but maybe some of you already solved this problem.

Comment: No, It's not possible to create measures in PBI Service or in embedded.